# get the value of the cell in the line + n in the same column by comparing the boolean respective cell

Tags: google-sheets, filter, sum, boolean, google-sheets-formula

I feel stuck on an issue of which I am sure I will not find the answer because I might not have the right terms for my research on the search engine and it is rare that I am in such a blockage.
However, here is my issue: on another sheet i want to get a sum of value. On the picture below you can see few blocks represented by green circles and each block has a cell with check box in red circle and a value to get append to a sum by a blue circle. And this what i want, i want to get in my sum each blue circle value only if in the same block the check box is checked. This seem easy but my issue isn't there. I could get a condition if the check box is checked take the value for each block but maybe i want more block. This is my issue, i could get more block or someone else could get more or less block.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIZSV.png)

So i need a formula dynamic to get each future value in blue circle where futur red circle could be checked.

I hope my issue could be understand.

Comment: There is a general formula that would need to catch all those blue values in every row?, Or is it something that goes block by block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=SUM(FILTER(R7:R100; W4:W97=TRUE))
```

Comment: Thank you bro ! This is exactly what i needed. But I did not know that we could use a range in a filter while not taking all the values between the range